# Audit Log Plugin For Mysql 5.7.39 GBL

Tags: mysql, audit

I was using mariadb audit log plugin in mysql 5.7.30 now I moved into 5.7.39 and now this plugin is not supported. I configure mcafee audit log plugin but its producing too much log. Can you share any free audit log plugin which generates into CSV format or can we generate mcafee into CSV format rather than into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

We have got same issue

In fact, there is no viable alternative for MariaDB audit_plugin

Amazon MySQL audit plugin is working on RDS Amazon For MySQL
Code is freely available here:
https://github.com/aws/audit-plugin-for-mysql

But when try to complite in against MySQL 5.7.32 code, we realize that all needed code is not present and some files are missing